# How can i perform the right reverse query in ManytoMany in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to perform a reversed query for a `manytomany` fields in Django, but it keeps gives me nothing, here is my code

**models.py**

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products')
    branch = models.ManyToManyField(Branch, related_name='branches')

class Branch(models.Model):
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1200, null=True, blank=True)
    tax_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4)
```

**views.py**

```py
for branch in product_object.branches.all():
    print(branch)
```

The branch is always nothing !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the related name is not calling it anymore. I called it using the model name (lower cased).
This is how it worked

```py
for branch in product_object.branch.all():
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete your answer above, I think the way you have your model set up is a little misleading and confusing. I think this would improve clarity:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products')
    branches = models.ManyToManyField(Branch, related_name='products')
```

- Since you have a many to many field, a product can have multiple branches, the attribute name should reflect that
- When you use the `related_name`, this would be if you are going from the m2m object. For example, if you have a branch, you could get all it's products by doing `branch.products`